# How to write to txt from python wherein date from header is copied to every record in txt file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file which looks like below (snapshot only):

```
DC000D20221110012022100019
DC011D           AV0019000300080180003340501031800481200000
DC011D           AV0019000300083180003361901031900071900000
DC011D           AV0019000300089180003378701032100515800000
DC000D20221209012022100019
DC011D           CG0019000300080220100264401000000000000000
DC011D           CG0019000300080220400885101000039990700000
DC011D           CG0019000300080220400885101000040013000000
```

I have ~1m records this way for 3 years. The First record 'DC000D20221110012022100019' is the header for which has date at position [6:14]. I need to import this data into a dataframe for my exploratory analysis for which I need the date present for each record, not header. So I need something like this:

```
DC000D20221110012022100019
DC011D20221110   AV0019000300080180003340501031800481200000
DC011D20221110   AV0019000300083180003361901031900071900000
DC011D20221110   AV0019000300089180003378701032100515800000
DC000D20221209012022100019
DC011D20221209   CG0019000300080220100264401000000000000000
DC011D20221209   CG0019000300080220400885101000039990700000
DC011D20221209   CG0019000300080220400885101000040013000000
```

That way I can import it into pandas df easily.

Form the main text file as above I am preparing another txt file with only DC011 records as below:

#File for submodule DC011

```
File1=open(r"\path\CRGDEC\CRGDEC.txt")
File2=open(r"\path\CRGDEC_DC011.txt", "w")

for line in File1.readlines():
    if (line.startswith('DC011')):
        File2.write(line)
```

But this eliminates the DC000 header records and I can't use the fillna() option in my df to prepare the Date column.
Help is much appreciated!!

N.B. I have other modules in a similar way as well (such as DC012, DC013, DC014).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just add an if to check for the header record, you can also write it (and memorize the date to append to the subsequent lines)

```
File1=open(r"\path\CRGDEC\CRGDEC.txt")
File2=open(r"\path\CRGDEC_DC011.txt", "w")

saveDate = ""   # just in case
for line in File1.readlines():
    if (line.startswith('DC000'):
        saveDate = line[6:14]
        File2.write(line)
    if (line.startswith('DC011')):
       line2write = line[:6] + saveDate + line[7:]
        File2.write(line2write)
```

I didn't test this, but it should be near correct.

Comment: Many thanks, the only thing was to declare the variable line2write in advance, and it worked perfectly fine!

saveDate = ""   # just in case
line2write = ""
for line in File1.readlines():
    if (line.startswith('DC000')):
        saveDate = line[6:14]
        File2.write(line)
    if (line.startswith('DC030')):
       line2write = line[:6] + saveDate + line[7:]
    File2.write(line2write)

Answer (score 0):

You can import in pandas directly by specifying the separator and the column names in `read_csv`. Then proceed with some operations to get the desired format:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""DC000D20221110012022100019
DC011D           AV0019000300080180003340501031800481200000
DC011D           AV0019000300083180003361901031900071900000
DC011D           AV0019000300089180003378701032100515800000
DC000D20221209012022100019
DC011D           CG0019000300080220100264401000000000000000
DC011D           CG0019000300080220400885101000039990700000
DC011D           CG0019000300080220400885101000040013000000
""")

df =  pd.read_csv(data, sep=r"\s+", engine="python", names=['ref', 'value'])
df['date'] = df.loc[df['value'].isna(), 'ref'].str[6:14]
df['date'] = df['date'].ffill()
mask = ~df['value'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'ref'] = df[mask]['ref'] + df[mask]['date']
print(df.drop(columns='date'))
```

Output:

```
                          ref                                       value
0  DC000D20221110012022100019                                        None
1              DC011D20221110  AV0019000300080180003340501031800481200000
2              DC011D20221110  AV0019000300083180003361901031900071900000
3              DC011D20221110  AV0019000300089180003378701032100515800000
4  DC000D20221209012022100019                                        None
5              DC011D20221209  CG0019000300080220100264401000000000000000
6              DC011D20221209  CG0019000300080220400885101000039990700000
7              DC011D20221209  CG0019000300080220400885101000040013000000
```